# Can I use mongdb data in my v4.4.5 database that was exported from v3.6.3?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongoexport

I have a mongodb database with version 3.6.3. I have another mongodb database (on another machine) using version 4.4.5 with no documents in it. I want to put the data from the v3.6.3 into the v4.4.5 database. Can I safetly do this using mongoexport and then mongoimport or do I need to perform more steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, mongoexport writes the documents out to a JSON file, and mongoimport can read that file and insert the documents to the new database.

These will transfer only the documents, but not index information.  You many want to consider [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/)/[mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/) if you also need to move indexes.

Comment: See [Restore to Matching Server Version](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#restore-to-matching-server-version): *When using mongorestore to load data files created by mongodump, be sure that you are restoring to the same major version of the MongoDB Server that the files were created from.* - So. dump from 3.6.3 may not work for target 4.4.5

Comment: I totally missed that section in the docs.  I guess I've just been lucky that it has worked whenever I needed to do that.